# MongoDB: addToSet not working when adding subdocuments to an array

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am stuck trying to get unique subdocuments in an array.

A document in my collection looks like this:

```
 {
    "PubDate": "1/01/01 00:00", 
    "Title": "Identification of DNA-Dependent Protein Kinase Catalytic Subunit (DNA-PKcs) as a Novel Target of Bisphenol A", 
    "Datums": [
                {
                    "evidence_id": "3515620_6",
                    "evidence": [
                      "\n\nTo examine the interaction between DNA-PKcs and Ku70/Ku80 more directly, we performed immunoprecipitation (IP) using FLAG-Ku70 or FLAG-Ku80 recombinants, which were expressed in 293T cells after IR-irradiation (Fig. 4B\n                                    ) or UV-irradiation (Fig. 4C\n                                    ). After IR-irradiation, co-precipitation of DNA-PKcs with Ku80 increased compared with that in the non-irradiated controls (Fig. 4B\n                                     lanes 7 and 8)."
                    ],
                    "map": {
                      "change": [
                        {
                          "Text": "increased"

                        }
                      ],
                      "subject": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],
                      "treatment": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],

                      "assay": [
                        {
                          "Text": "copptby"

                        }
                      ]     
                    }
                  },
                {
                    "evidence_id": "3515620_6",
                    "evidence": [
                      "\n\nTo examine the interaction between DNA-PKcs and Ku70/Ku80 more directly, we performed immunoprecipitation (IP) using FLAG-Ku70 or FLAG-Ku80 recombinants, which were expressed in 293T cells after IR-irradiation (Fig. 4B\n                                    ) or UV-irradiation (Fig. 4C\n                                    ). After IR-irradiation, co-precipitation of DNA-PKcs with Ku80 increased compared with that in the non-irradiated controls (Fig. 4B\n                                     lanes 7 and 8)."
                    ],
                    "map": {
                      "change": [
                        {
                          "Text": "increased"

                        }
                      ],
                      "subject": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],
                      "treatment": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],

                      "assay": [
                        {
                          "Text": "copptby"

                        }
                      ]

                    }
                  },
                {
                    "evidence_id": "3515620_6",
                    "evidence": [
                      "\n\nTo examine the interaction between DNA-PKcs and Ku70/Ku80 more directly, we performed immunoprecipitation (IP) using FLAG-Ku70 or FLAG-Ku80 recombinants, which were expressed in 293T cells after IR-irradiation (Fig. 4B\n                                    ) or UV-irradiation (Fig. 4C\n                                    ). After IR-irradiation, co-precipitation of DNA-PKcs with Ku80 increased compared with that in the non-irradiated controls (Fig. 4B\n                                     lanes 7 and 8)."
                    ],
                    "map": {
                      "change": [
                        {
                          "Text": "increased"

                        }
                      ],
                      "subject": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],
                      "treatment": [
                        {
                          "Entity": {
                            "strings": [
                              "dna-pkcs"
                            ],
                            "uniprotSym": "P78527"
                          }

                        }
                      ],

                      "assay": [
                        {
                          "Text": "copptby"

                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
            ], 
"Volume": "7", 
"FullJournalName": "PLoS ONE", 
"Authors": "Ito Y, Ito T, Karasawa S, Enomoto T, Nashimoto A, Hase Y, Sakamoto S, Mimori T, Matsumoto Y, Yamaguchi Y, Handa H", 
"Issue": "12", 
"Pages": "e50481", 
"PMCID": "3515620"
}
```

In the above example, the "Datums" field has only one subdocument, but usually, the "Datums" field will have around 20-30 subdocuments. I want my MongoDB query to output documents (that satisfy certain criteria), where the "Datums" field will have unique subdocuments in its array. To do that I am using the following MongoDB query:

```
db.My_Datums.aggregate(
[
    { "$match": {
        "Datums":
        {
            "$elemMatch": 
            {
                    "map.treatment.Entity.uniprotSym": { "$in": ["P33981", "P78527"] },
                    "map.assay.Text": "copptby"
            }

        }
    }},
    { "$project": { "PMCID":1, "Title":1, "PubDate":1, "Volume":1, "Issue":1, "Pages":1, "FullJournalName":1, "Authors":1, "Datums.map.assay.Text":1, "Datums.map.change.Text":1, "Datums.map.subject.Entity.strings":1, "Datums.map.treatment.Entity.uniprotSym":1, "Datums.evidence_id":1, "_id":0 }},
    { "$unwind": "$Datums" },
    { "$match": { "Datums.map.treatment.Entity.uniprotSym": { "$in": ["P33981", "P78527"] }, "Datums.map.assay.Text": "copptby" }},                
    { "$group": { "_id": "$PMCID", "Datums": { "$addToSet": "$Datums" }}}
] 
#{ allowDiskUse: 1 }
)
```

But on running the above command, I am getting the below output:

```
{u'Datums': [{u'evidence_id': u'3515620_6',
          u'map': {u'assay': [{u'Text': u'copptby'}],
                   u'change': [{u'Text': u'increased'}],
                   u'subject': [{u'Entity': {u'strings': u'dna-pkcs'}}],
                   u'treatment': [{u'Entity': {u'uniprotSym': u'P78527'}}]}},
         {u'evidence_id': u'3515620_6',
          u'map': {u'assay': [{u'Text': u'copptby'}],
                   u'change': [{u'Text': u'increased'}],
                   u'subject': [{u'Entity': {u'strings': u'dna-pkcs'}}],
                   u'treatment': [{u'Entity': {u'uniprotSym': u'P78527'}}]}},
         {u'evidence_id': u'3515620_6',
          u'map': {u'assay': [{u'Text': u'copptby'}],
                   u'change': [{u'Text': u'increased'}],
                   u'subject': [{u'Entity': {u'strings': u'dna-pkcs'}}],
                   u'treatment': [{u'Entity': {u'uniprotSym': u'P78527'}}]}}],
u'_id': u'3515620'}
```

What I am not understanding is why addToSet adding duplicate subdocuments to "Datums". Is there any way I can filter out the duplicates? What am I doing wrong in my query? I have searched a lot and read up a lot, but couldnt find any solution. Any MongoDB guru out there who could help this noob?? I will be eternally grateful to you!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either your query is mistyped here quite drastically or it is not actually working at all. The `$in` arguments need to be an array of arguments and not a singular string as you have represented them, otherwise this would error. I would suggest editing your question to include at least three documents relevant to the result with just the required fields for ease of reading. That way people can clearly see what is wrong here. Your single sample does not corelate to the result, so right now no-one can test.

Comment: Hi Blakes, I had mistyped my query while trying to remove complexities.. I have added the array that I am actually trying to search using the `$in` argument. I have also given an example document that will result in the above output. My documents are huge so I have formatted it the best I can. You can ignore the 'evidence' key if you do not want to scroll horizontally. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem here is that the "values" you are looking to match in your query are not present in the "data" you have presented. That is why I asked for *"three documents containing the data as shown in the result"* since the "aggregatation" is occurring over "multiple" documents. You are only showing **one** document ( that does not match results ) and therefore we have nothing to test against. In order to "solve" your problem we need the "same" input that produces the "same" output ( in a minimal case ). Without that, cannot help.

Comment: It's **still** just a "singular" document. No data to form "duplicates" here. You need to include more data. Which is the same statement I have made three times now.

Comment: I want to match against "map.treatment.Entity.uniprotSym" and "map.assay.Text". The document I have given here matches the values I am looking for in the query. Yeah, I have shown one document. If you see my result output, you will notice it is coming from this document. The result I have shown does not come from different documents. I am not sure what you are suggesting. Do you have questions about my query? Let me know I can explain what I am trying to do..

Comment: Make that **Four** times ( so I guess the third isn't the charm ). **YOUR QUESTION ONLY CONTAINS ONE DOCUMENT** We cannot reproduce with only one document. No other explainations needed. JUST EDIT YOUR QUESTION TO INCLUDE MORE DOCUMENTS.

Comment: At first you said how the document I presented does not match the values I am looking for (did you even read my query or go through the result?). Now you are like just give more documents.. The data I have given here is just for representation purposes. Dude, if you are so good in MongoDB like the way you are acting, you dont need data. You would have been able to find the problem, if any exists, just by looking at the query. I wont be able to give you more data, since I have to edit it first and the documents are huge.. also, I dont think you will be able to help anyways.. So thanks!